# How to emit safe URL in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, url, escaping

Consider the following code in Django template:

```
<a href='{{target}}'>Link text</a>
```

or

```
<a href="{{target}}">Link text</a>
```

If the context item `target` contains quote or double-quote characters (`'` or `"`), then I expect the HTML page to break at a minimum. Or someone can insert JavaScript after closing the quote/double-quote, so to run arbitrary code on clients' machines.

How to escape the url in such cases?

I've tried

```
<a href='{{target|urlencode}}'>Link text</a>
```

But the problem with this approach is that the URL stops leading to the original site like `http://www.example.com` , but starts leading to my site with `http://www.example.com` treated as the path after the domain name, i.e. it becomes `http://127.0.0.1:8000/http%3A//www.example.com`.

So could you tell me the correct approach to make URLs safe?

UPDATE: I've just realized that my example is too simplified. Here's how I use the context item, if more elaborate:

```
<a href="javascript:{}"
    onclick="return recordTarget({{ target.perm_id }}, '{{ target.link }}')">
    {{ target.title }}</a>
```

So I'm already using single quotes and double quotes in the HTML. `target.link` is passed as a string to JavaScript function.

How can I change my code to be safe and working in case the URL contains single or double quotes?

Comment: Django will automatically HTML encode this (unless you apply a `safe` filter), so `&quot;`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , I'm using Django 2.1 and my tests show it doesn't automatically HTML-encode this.... `"http://test'em.all/"`

Comment: single quotes have no escaping, that is why it is advisable to use double quotes to surround attribute values, only double quotes are escaped.

Comment: That's strange... it seems encoded in HTML page as `&#39;`, however, Chrome fails to execute this line when passed to JavaScript. Perhaps it's a bug in Chrome...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I've updated the question. The problem is that I'm already using both single and double quotes in the HTML and I don't see a way to avoid that.